# How to configure coredump location/path to be process specific?

Tags: c, linux

I have two processes of the same program running. I need them to coredump at different configurable locations. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Check "man 5 core"
If you write a string to /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern it can control the name given to core files.
This can include $p for the pid - to keep the cores separate.

Comment: I think that should be [`%p`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/core.5.html) not `$p`.